# Bluetooth on Easynote te69bm not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I've just starting using Ubuntu (LTS 14.04), so the issue could be a piece of cake but I have no idea of how to solve it As I wrote in the title, my bluetooth is not working. Seems to be activated (bluetooth and visibility are ON) but I cannot pair any device.

I've tried some of the solutions written in other posts but they didn't work.

```
ls /var/lib/bluetooth/:  14:2D:27:16:28:E0

cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9434609/

rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
```

I've changed `ReverseServiceDiscovery = false` but it's still not working.

`lspci -v` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9603958/)

Comment: What hardware are you using? (you can the output of `lspci -v` and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/564459/edit) it into your question)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you feel comfortable patching kernel modules you may want until Ubuntu supports your bluetooth device and that could be the next kernel release.  Please do a `lsusb` (please insert into post) in terminal, you will see a list of devices found on you computer, one will likely be a FoxConn device with [0489:????] I have a good idea you will find [0489:e078] which is not supported correctly in the 3.13.0-43 kernel but eventually it will be supported by the Ubuntu kernel as it is correct in bluetooth-next

Comment: you were right!
lsusb `Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b3d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e078 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`